# Change other vendors config files

Tags: laravel-4, configuration

When you see `Config::get('app.locale')` you can open `app/config/app.php` file and change the value of `locale` key. But something like this: `Config::get('package::file.key')` is located in `vendor` directory (`./vendor/vendorname/package/src/config/file.php`).

How should I change the value of `package::file.key`? Changing it inside `vendor` directory isn't possible because we always ignore this directory in our repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `php artisan config:publish packagename`

```
php artisan config:publish -h
Usage:
 config:publish [--path[="..."]] [--force] package
```

This will create a copy of the config file in `app/config/packages/[package]`, this one you can edit and keep in version control.

### Edit for Laravel 5

---

In Laravel 5 you can use

`php artisan vendor:publish`

Which will display a list of vendors to publish assets from.

When available in the package, you can also use tags to specify which part you want to publish, e.g. public, config, etc.

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=config`

Comment: Thanks. But I had to include `vendorname` in the command. `php artisan config:publish vendorname/packagename`

Comment: Ah.. Yeah should have clarified that a bit more perhaps, anyway good to see you got it to work